# How to transfer data from multiple columns into one (without sorting)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms

I'm using Google Forms to collect peoples' availability and then centralizing all that into a spreadsheet where scheduling is then done. Pretty easy.

The people are separated into various categories in the forms, so when their names are shown in the spreadsheet they get recorded into different columns (B:G).

What I'd like to do is enter a formula that will automatically transfer any names from B:G into the A cells, which is where the entire spreadsheet is matching names to populate where to schedule the people. Essentially, all the names should automatically be placed in the A column. Hopefully that makes sense.

Here's an example sheet that is identical to what I'm working with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bxjpyEBvrcb-7o3QKIuG-c5Yu6JFiu66h3huHt0kjM0/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in A2 and copy down:

```
=iferror(JOIN("",B16:G16))
```